# Get a list - like "tree" - of all files in a directory but using their "title" attribute

Tags: tree, attributes, rename, filenames, title

I have a directory with hundreds of files in it, all with pretty meaningless codename filenames.  However, the "title" attribute on each file - which I can see by adding the "title" column in windows explorer - is meaningful.  Is there any way I can get an output of all the files, like I can with `tree`, but where the file's title is displayed instead of the filename?  Or perhaps if there was a way to automatically rename every file in the directory with each file's title, and then I could just run tree on that?!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find an excellent, free tool Advanced Renamer (https://www.advancedrenamer.com/download) that allows me to rename all the files in the directory.  I used the tag `<ExifTool:title>` which picked up the title perfectly for all the files.  Once they're renamed I can run the tree app on it to get the list I need.